# QMap is returning null value even with a correct key (the key has the same address: couldn't be incorrect?)

Tags: c++, qt, dictionary, qmap

I have a QMap and I insert a key-value pair into in one function, but when I try to access that value (using the same key) in a different function I get a null value.

I wanted to include all the code just to be safe (it's below), but really the question is boiled down to: why am I getting a null value when I access the map using the same key (I know that I'm using the same key because I print the key's address and it's the same both times).

```
class Something 
 {
      QMap<QPushButton*,QWidget*> map;

 };

 Something::exampleFunction()
 {
      QPushButton* myButton = new QPushButton(someParent);
      QWidget* widget = new QWidget(someParent);

      connect(myButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(onButtonPress()));
      this->map[myButton] = widget;

      cout<<"Address of myButton: " << myButton << "\n";

      cout<<"Address of widget: " << this->map[myButton] << "\n";
      //the above line outputs the address of the widget, which means
      //the qmap is working just fine?
 }

 Something::onButtonPress()
 {
      QPushButton* buttonInFunction = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(sender());
      QWidget* widgetInFunction = this->map[buttonInFunction];

      cout<<"Address of button within function: " << button;
      //the above line prints the same address as 
      //was printed for the button in exampleFunction

      cout << "Address of widget within function:" << widgetInFunction; 
      //the above line outputs 16 zeros, i.e. null
 }
```

Comment: Without more code, I'm going to speculate 1. map was cleared or 2. It's two different instance of `Something`.

Comment: This is obviously not code you've ever tried compiling (because it doesn't compile, I fixed some obvious mistakes). Please share an example that actually compiles and produces the behavior you described. Please read about [MCVE].